# Setting Bean properties in java based config without constructor or setter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

I'm trying to setup Velocity template engine to use with spring-mvc.
My project currently uses only java based spring configuration.

I have trouble setting up `VelocityConfigurer`.

According to Spring documentation I should create bean as follows:

```
<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
  <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/velocity/"/>
</bean>
```

I currently have the following related configuration, but cannot seem to find a way to inject "resourceLoaderPath" property. `VelocityConfigurer` class does not have corresponding setter or constructor.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public VelocityConfigurer velocityConfig() {
        VelocityConfigurer velocityConfigurer = new VelocityConfigurer();
        return velocityConfigurer;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to avoid .xml based configuration here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the javadoc the [VelocityConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/velocity/VelocityConfigurer.html) has a setter for the [resourceLoaderPath](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactory.html#setResourceLoaderPath%28java.lang.String%29). The setter is inherited from the [VelocityEngineFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactory.html).

So it should be possible to set it:

```
@Bean
public VelocityConfigurer velocityConfig() {
    VelocityConfigurer velocityConfigurer = new VelocityConfigurer();
    velocityConfigurer.setResourceLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/velocity/");
    return velocityConfigurer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I must be getting blind. :(